# How do I convert Unicode escape sequences to Unicode characters in a .NET string?

Tags: c#, .net, unicode

Say you've loaded a text file into a string, and you'd like to convert all Unicode escapes into actual Unicode characters inside of the string.

Example:

> "The following is the top half of an integral character in Unicode '\u2320', and this is the lower half '\U2321'."

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The answer is simple and works well with strings up to at least several thousand characters.

Example 1:

```
Regex  rx = new Regex( @"\\[uU]([0-9A-F]{4})" );
result = rx.Replace( result, match => ((char) Int32.Parse(match.Value.Substring(2), NumberStyles.HexNumber)).ToString() );
```

Example 2:

```
Regex  rx = new Regex( @"\\[uU]([0-9A-F]{4})" );
result = rx.Replace( result, delegate (Match match) { return ((char) Int32.Parse(match.Value.Substring(2), NumberStyles.HexNumber)).ToString(); } );
```

The first example shows the replacement being made using a lambda expression (C# 3.0) and the second uses a delegate which should work with C# 2.0.

To break down what's going on here, first we create a regular expression:

```
new Regex( @"\\[uU]([0-9A-F]{4})" );
```

Then we call Replace() with the string 'result' and an anonymous method (lambda expression in the first example and the delegate in the second - the delegate could also be a regular method) that converts each regular expression that is found in the string.

The Unicode escape is processed like this:

```
((char) Int32.Parse(match.Value.Substring(2), NumberStyles.HexNumber)).ToString(); });
```

Get the string representing the number part of the escape (skip the first two characters).

```
match.Value.Substring(2)
```

Parse that string using Int32.Parse() which takes the string and the number format that the Parse() function should expect which in this case is a hex number.

```
NumberStyles.HexNumber
```

Then we cast the resulting number to a Unicode character:

```
(char)
```

And finally we call ToString() on the Unicode character which gives us its string representation which is the value passed back to Replace():

```
.ToString()
```

Note: Instead of grabbing the text to be converted with a Substring call you could use the match parameter's GroupCollection, and a subexpressions in the regular expression to capture just the number ('2320'), but that's more complicated and less readable.

Comment: \u and \U should be treated differently -- \u specifies 4 hex digits (16 bits), where \U specifies 8 (32 bits) -- a unicode codepoint is 21 bits long.  Also, you should use the char.ConvertFromUtf32() method rather than a cast.

Comment: I've seen \u and \U documented both ways though the current C# language specification indicates 4 hex bytes for \u and 8 hex bytes for \U. In any case, \U with only 4 hex digits is processed correctly. Have to check if ConvertFromUtf32() is functionally different from a cast.

Comment: Yeah, I read the ignorecase option in the second part of the post after realising myself. Thanks all the same. :)

Comment: This is a brilliant answer!
Just one point, in my case a-f letters were lower case so this is maybe more accurate:
    var rx = new Regex(@"\\[uU]([0-9A-Fa-f]{4})");

Comment: The first part should say result = rx.Replace(... rather than result = rxx.Replace(....

I'd fix it myself but stackoverflow does not allow edits of fewer than 6 characters because the stackexchange higher ups think they know better than professionals actually using the site.

Answer (score 10):

Refactored a little more:

```
Regex regex = new Regex (@"\\U([0-9A-F]{4})", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
string line = "...";
line = regex.Replace (line, match => ((char)int.Parse (match.Groups[1].Value,
  NumberStyles.HexNumber)).ToString ());
```

Answer (score 8):

This is the VB.NET equivalent:

```
Dim rx As New RegularExpressions.Regex("\\[uU]([0-9A-Fa-f]{4})")
result = rx.Replace(result, Function(match) CChar(ChrW(Int32.Parse(match.Value.Substring(2), Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber))).ToString())
```

Answer (score 2):

add `UnicodeExtensions.cs` class to your project:

```
public static class UnicodeExtensions
{
    private static readonly Regex Regex = new Regex(@"\\[uU]([0-9A-Fa-f]{4})");

    public static string UnescapeUnicode(this string str)
    {
        return Regex.Replace(str,
            match => ((char) int.Parse(match.Value.Substring(2),
                NumberStyles.HexNumber)).ToString());
    }
}
```

usage:

```
var test = "\\u0074\\u0068\\u0069\\u0073 \\u0069\\u0073 \\u0074\\u0065\\u0073\\u0074\\u002e";
var output = test.UnescapeUnicode();   // output is => this is test.
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you better add the small letters to your regular expression. It worked better for me.

```
Regex rx = new Regex(@"\\[uU]([0-9A-Fa-f]{4})");
result = rx.Replace(result, match => ((char) Int32.Parse(match.Value.Substring(2), NumberStyles.HexNumber)).ToString());
```