# Char.ConvertFromUtf32 not available in Silverlight

Tags: vb.net, silverlight

I'm converting a WinForms app to Silverlight (VB.NET). What should I use instead of Char.ConvertFromUtf32 as it's not available to use in Silverlight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UTF-32 is currently not part of Silverlight, so you have to find a way around the limitation. I think you should stop a moment and think exactly why you need to read UTF32-encoded text.

- **If you are reading such text from a database or a file on the server**, I would perform the conversion server-side (if possible I would convert everything to UTF-8 and get rid of the UTF-32 data in one shot).
- **If you are parsing a user-provided file on the client side**, I would detect the UTF-32 encoding and gently tell the user that the file encoding is not supported. UTF32 is pretty rare nowadays, so I guess it should not be a very common case (but I could be wrong not knowing your exact situation).

In order to detect the file encoding you have to look at the first few bytes (byte order mark) -more information [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/761eda46-f5f6-43cc-9a52-b4c7225fc96d), if they are not present the task becomes much harder and involves some kind of heuristics based on character frequency.

Comment: Parsing a JSON is common and you can't ask anyone to change `\u0000` or `\u001F` to another representation, as it is unique in JSON.

Answer (score 0):

From: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/how-to-convert-between-hexadecimal-strings-and-numeric-types

You can use a direct cast, like:

```
// Get the character corresponding to the integral value.
string stringValue = Char.ConvertFromUtf32(value);
char charValue = (char)value;
```

Small warning, it will only work up to 0xffff. It will not work for high range Unicode from 0x10000 to 0x10ffff.

Also, if you need to parse *\uXXXX*, try this other question: [How do I convert Unicode escape sequences to Unicode characters in a .NET string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183907/how-do-convert-unicode-escape-sequences-to-unicode-characters-in-a-net-string)