# Backslash read and write and F# interactive console

Tags: f#

Edit: whats the difference between reading a backslash from a file and writing it to the interactive window  vs writing directly the string to the interactive window ?

For example

```
let toto = "Adelaide Gu\u00e9nard" 

toto;;
```

the interactive window prints "Adelaide Guénard".

Now if I save a txt file with the single line Adelaide Gu\u00e9nard . And read it in:

```
System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"test.txt")
```

The interactive window prints [|"Adelaide Gu\u00e9nard"|]

What is the difference between these 2 statements in terms of the interactive window printing ?

Comment: It sounds like your text files contains a backslash and a 'u' and some numbers in it, yes?  And I guess you want to 'interpret' those characters like an F# string literal?  (Just trying to clarify the question, I don't know the answer.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no library that would decode the F#/C# escaping of string for you, so you'll have to implement that functionality yourself. There was a similar question on [how to do that in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183907/how-do-convert-unicode-escape-sequences-to-unicode-characters-in-a-net-string) with a solution using regular expressions.

You can rewrite that to F# like this:

```
open System
open System.Globalization
open System.Text.RegularExpressions

let regex = new Regex (@"\\[uU]([0-9A-F]{4})", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
let line = "Adelaide Gu\\u00e9nard"
let line = regex.Replace(line, fun (m:Match) -> 
  (char (Int32.Parse(m.Groups.[1].Value, NumberStyles.HexNumber))).ToString())
```

(If you write `"some\\u00e9etc"` then you're creating string that contains the same thing as what you'd read from the text file - if you use single backslash, then the F# compiler interprets the escaping)

Answer (score 3):

It uses the [StructuredFormat](http://fsharppowerpack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/54799#685060) stuff from the F# PowerPack. For your string, it's effectively doing `printfn toto;;`.

You can achieve the same behaviour in a text file as follows:

```
open System.IO;;
File.WriteAllText("toto.txt", toto);;
```

The default encoding used by `File.WriteAllText` is UTF-8. You should be able to open toto.txt in Notepad or Visual Studio and see the é correctly.

**Edit:** *If wanted to write the content of test.txt to another file in the clean F# interactive print, how would i proceed ?*

It looks like fsi is being too clever when printing the contents of test.txt. It's formatting it as a valid F# expression, complete with quotes, `[| |]` brackets, and a Unicode character escape. The string returned by `File.ReadAllLines` doesn't contain any of these things; it just contains the words *Adelaide Guénard*.

You should be able to take the array returned by `File.ReadAllLines` and pass it to `File.WriteAllLines`, without the contents being mangled.

Comment: thank for the answer Tim I edited my question to illustrate more my problem.

Comment: so I tried the ReadAllLines and then WriteAllLines. It doesn't work. Thanks for the help