# C# and character decoding

Tags: c#, string, decode

I have a string \u0025A3\u0025A3... e.t.c. So how can I decode that to normal view in C#.

I mean sequence \u0025A3\u0025A3 should looks in decoded mode. For example, the \u0025A3\u0025A3 sequence should looks like "::".

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by normal view?

Comment: You know, the view that isn't weird.

Comment: @user591712: Why would it be "::"?

Comment: Are these Unicode Escape Sequences?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664669(v=vs.71).aspx  If so, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/183907/how-do-convert-unicode-escape-sequences-to-unicode-characters-in-a-net-string

Answer (score 0):

You can use  [split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228388%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) method to decode your string .

Answer (score 0):

The Unicode characters in your string are above \uFFFF so they will display as "?" in the default windows character set, or a "" in some apps. Try this anyway.

```
string test = "\\u0025A3\\u0025A3";
Regex rx = new Regex(@"\\[uU]([0-9A-F]{6})");
test = rx.Replace(test, match => char.ConvertFromUtf32(int.Parse(match.ToString().Substring(2), NumberStyles.HexNumber)));
```