# what`s this Encoding?

Tags: string, encoding, persian

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do convert unicode escape sequences to unicode characters in a .NET string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183907/how-do-convert-unicode-escape-sequences-to-unicode-characters-in-a-net-string)

im translating zimbra , and i confusing to know whats this string encoding and what tools i can use to convert utf-8 encoded string to this kind ?

**String:**

*errorMaintenanceMode* = `\u0628\u0627 \u0639\u0631\u0636 \u067E\u0648\u0632\u0634 \u062D\u0633\u0627\u0628 \u06A9\u0627\u0631\u0628\u0631\u06CC`

Comment: Dont know zimbra but had some clue with php. you can refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2934563/how-to-decode-unicode-escape-sequences-like-u00ed-to-proper-utf-8-encoded-cha

Comment: Is that supposed to be "با عرض پوزش حساب کاربری"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those code points reside in the Arabic block of the Unicode [Basic Multilingual Plane (BMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_%28Unicode%29#Basic_Multilingual_Plane)). I determined this using [BabelMap](http://www.babelstone.co.uk/unicode/babelmap.html). There is an [online version](http://www.babelstone.co.uk/unicode/babelmap.html) you can use as well.

Using the application you can convert between:

`\u0628\u0627 \u0639\u0631\u0636 \u067E\u0648\u0632\u0634 \u062D\u0633\u0627\u0628 \u06A9\u0627\u0631\u0628\u0631\u06CC`

and:

`با عرض پوزش حساب کاربری`

For programmatic tools look at the [ICU Project](http://site.icu-project.org/).

Comment: Yes, r u interested ? :)

Comment: @Robert Just a question, what block you where selected in BabelMap.com ?

Comment: @bizzare In the online version just enter any code point in the textbox next to the "Go To U+" button and then click the button and it will take you to the block where the character resides.

Comment: @AdilSoomro Yes, I meant to have said that those code points reside on the Arabic block of the BMP. I'll edit to clarify.