# How can I convert a string to Unicode?

Tags: c#, encoding, character-encoding

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do convert unicode escape sequences to unicode characters in a .NET string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183907/how-do-convert-unicode-escape-sequences-to-unicode-characters-in-a-net-string)

I have a string

```
\u0110\u1eb7ng Minh Khi\u00eam
```

which it is supposed to be in Unicode:

```
Đặng Minh Khiêm
```

How can I convert this string to Unicode in C#? It means convert

```
\u0110\u1eb7ng Minh Khi\u00eam =====> Đặng Minh Khiêm
```

Comment: The most upvoted answer to the duplicate question linked above will solve your problem (I verified)

Comment: which string format is this in==>\u0110\u1eb7ng Minh Khi\u00eam