# unicode to human readable string c# .net

Tags: c#, unicode-string

This is probably a very basic question, but really appreciate if you could help me with this:

I want to convert an string that contains characters like `\u000d\u000a\u000d\u000` to a human readable string, however I don't want to use .Replace method since the Unicode characters might be much more than what I include the software to check and replace.

```
string = "Test \u000d\u000a\u000d\u000aTesting with new line. \u000d\u000a\u000d\u000aone more new line"
```

I receive this string as a json Object from my server.

Comment: Can you just use it to display?

Comment: One possibility is described here:

[How do convert unicode escape sequences to unicode characters in a .NET string][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/183907/how-do-convert-unicode-escape-sequences-to-unicode-characters-in-a-net-string

Comment: thanks @uncoder I just used "Regex.Unescape(str)" wondering if this is a safe and sounds way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Do you even need that?

For example, the following code will print **abc** which is the actual decoded value:

```
var unicodeString = "\u0061\u0062\u0063";
Console.WriteLine(unicodeString);
```

Comment: yes unfortunately the UI element in the software shows all the unicode characters..

Comment: Well, there is difference between ``"\u0033"`` and ``"\\u0033"`` The first one contains an escape sequence ``\u`` which indicates a Unicode character. The second one simply starts with an escaped backslash (and that's what you're seeing in your app.)